# How to change the width of one facet in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a faceted barplot and one of the groups has fewer members than the others. I can plot it with only the groups that are present by setting `scales = "free_x"` but the facet is the same width as the others and so the bars are wider. This is distracting and I don't think I can submit the figure for publication as it is. I know the faceting functions in ggplot2 used to allow you to adjust the width of individual facets but this no longer appears to be the case.

Here's an example. I would like to make the right hand facet narrower so that the bars are the same width as the others. Any help much appreciated.

```
response<-rnorm(42, mean=10)
factor1<-factor(rep(c("A","B","C"), each=14))
factor2<-factor(rep(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2), times=3))
factor3<-factor(rep(c("X","X","X","Y","Y","Y","X","X","X","Y","Y","Y","Y","Y"),times=3))
factor4<-factor(rep(c(rep(c("27 degrees","30 degrees"), each=6),"33 degrees","33 degrees"), times=3))

data1<-data.frame(response,factor1,factor2,factor3,factor4)


p1<- ggplot(data=data1, aes(x=factor2, y=response, fill=factor1))
p1<- p1+geom_bar(stat="identity")
p1<- p1+facet_grid(~factor4+factor3,scales = "free_x")+theme_bw()
p1<- p1+scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+theme(strip.background=element_rect( fill="white"))
p1<- p1 + scale_fill_brewer(guide = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))
p1
```

This gives:

[image]

Comment: add `space="free_x"` inside `facet_grid`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to emphasize the lack of data for the "missing" bar, then do `p1 + scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE)`.

Comment: Also, you don't need to update `p1` on each line. You can just string all the statements together: `p1 = ggplot(data=data1, aes(x=factor2, y=response, fill=factor1)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + ...` etc.

Comment: Some of us find it easier to edit / debug long ggplot2 chains with the `+` method @eipi10

Comment: And some of us don't, but you can't make the choice that works best for you unless you know that both options are available.